# Accessing Item.To in outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

In a macro I need to access the names in Item.To while typing an email.
For example while typing the email goto the tools menu and run the macro from the 'macro' submenu.

When the code trys to use Item.To there is a debug exception and the debug tool tells me "Object required".

I can access Item.To durring Application_ItemSend, so I have part of it right.

Thanks for thinking about it, I am stuck on this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to access the To line in the past using code similar to this:

```
With Application.ActiveInspector
    If TypeOf .CurrentItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Debug.Print "To: " & .CurrentItem.To

        'If you want to access each recipient
        Set myRecipients = .CurrentItem.Recipients
        Dim myRecipient As recipient
        Dim recipientToList As New Collection

        For Each myRecipient In myRecipients
                recipientToList.Add myRecipient.Name                
        Next

    End If
End With
```

I have loaded up an `ArrayList` with each recipient to use for sorting, etc.

Comment: Thank you!!  Works perfect.  I have added the following sub to my list of macros to try out your code: